# Find entries depending from actual date

Tags: mysql

How could I find some specific entries from a database table.
I need the values of ref when today's date is betwenn start and end and the state is 1. If the date is not between start and end then I need the values of ref if start and end are '0000-00-00' and the state is 1.

`ref      start        end state
  1 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  1 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     1
  2 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     0
  2 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     0
  3 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  4 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     0
  5 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  5 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     0
  6 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  6 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     1
  7 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  7 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
  8 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1 
  8 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
  9 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1 
  9 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
 10 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     0 
 10 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     1
 11 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 11 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
 12 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 12 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
 13 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 13 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     0
 14 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     0
 14 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     1
 15 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 15 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     0
 16 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 16 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     0
 17 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
 17 2015-05-23 2015-09-04     0`

Comment: Is having date values of `0000-00-00` a common thing in your database?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select ref
from table
where state = 1
    and ((mydate between start and end)
    or (start = 0000-00-00 and end=0000-00-00 and mydate not between start and end))
```

Answer (score 1):

The entries in the table were different than I expected. See example data below the following query. This query does exacly what I need:

```
SELECT ref FROM table  
LEFT JOIN (  
SELECT ref AS def_ref, COUNT(ref) AS count1  
  FROM table  
  WHERE start = mydate  
  GROUP BY def  
) def ON pi.hausnr = def_ref  
WHERE IF(  
  start = mydate  
  , state = 1  
  IF(  
    start = '0000-00-00' AND end = '0000-00-00' AND count1 IS NULL  
    , state = 1  
    0  
  )  
)
```

There could be only one entry for a 'ref'-Number with 0000-00-00 as value for start and end. Or there are multiply entries. If there is an entry where mydate is between start and end then the entry with the same 'ref'-Number and 0000-00-00 should be ignored.

`ref      start        end state
  1 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  2 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     0
  3 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  4 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  4 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     0
  5 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  5 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     0
  5 2015-09-06 2015-10-09     1
  5 2015-10-10 2015-10-22     0
  6 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  6 2015-07-18 2015-09-05     1
  7 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1
  7 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
  8 0000-00-00 0000-00-00     1 
  8 2015-06-27 2015-09-04     0
...`